# Will higher grade thrusters have any effect if my ship is already below the optimal weight of my current thrusters?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I'm currently working out a loadout for my Vulture, which is a very light ship with high class (class 5) thrusters. It's a very light ship, weighing in at less than 500 tons at the absolute heaviest (in a very, very ridiculous setup).

Class 5E thrusters have an optimal mass of 560 tons, so even at its heaviest, the vulture is still well within that optimal range. Is there any real benefit to putting 5A thrusters on this ship?

Comment: I lied, [the heaviest this ship can get is 527 tons](http://www.edshipyard.com/#/L=60N,A5eA5e0_g0_g0_g0_g,316a886a50886a5A,17615Y12Q10s10s), which is still below 560, and also well outside the realm of reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**. Optimal mass is what the module was "designed" for. If your mass is exactly the same as the optimal thruster mass, your flight model will be precisely the flight model of the ship. If your mass is less, you will get an improved flight model. ([Source](https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php?t=47014&p=837944&viewfull=1#post837944))

In other words, class A thrusters will be more maneuverable in every single case.

Comment: The word "optimal" is misleading. It should be called something more like "calibrated" mass.

Comment: To clarify, it just makes your ship change speeds faster, hence, more maneuverability. Not a big deal for ships that aren't going to be combat-oriented, but for a Vulture, it's mandatory to get the highest-grade thrusters.